# Prevent programmer from using any trick to access private class member

Tags: c++

By declaring a member private, non-friend function can not access that member directly. But there is a way to access them by using pointer's type-cast, For instance:

```
class Foo {

  private:
    int value;

  public:
    inline int get() {
      return value;
    }
    inline Foo (int value) {
      Foo::value = value;
    }

} foo(1234);

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  cout << foo.display() << endl; // display 1234
  int *p = (int *)(&foo); // HERE!
  *p = 5678;
  cout << foo.display() << endl; // display 5678, foo.value has been changed
  return 0;
}
```

Can we prevent user to use these tricks? Or can we forbid converting `Foo *` to `int *`?

Comment: Short answer: You can't.

Comment: Your code has *undefined behaviour* BTW.

Comment: @juanchopanza My compiler - GCC compiled this without any warnings and errors.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve / avoid?

Comment: @DMaster `*p = 5678;` is UB though.

Comment: @DMaster The majority of code with undefined behavior compiles without any warnings and errors.

Comment: I wish I can forbid coverting `Foo *` to `int *`, I hope future standard of C++ provides that feature.

Comment: c++ is a relaxing language, it provide tools and warnings to help programmers but it usually do not forbid something explicit. If you do casting you get warnings (and indeed UB on alignment rule) if the compiler can emit code, and assume programmer knows what he is doing. What you looking for is a managed language which refuse to compiles on UB.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this?

Comment: Btw, you do not need to write `inline` when writing inline member functions. They are `inline` by default.

Comment: Highly recommended read: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm ("Uses and Abuses of Access Rights")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, no, it is not possible to prevent a determined programmer from doing an explicit type conversion, since there is an almost unlimited number of ways a determined enough programmer can exercise - particularly if willing to accept potential undefined behaviour.

Philosophically, the C++ type system is generally designed to make it harder to do things by accident.   However, it is not designed to prevent a programmer from deliberately subverting the type system.

It is possible to make things more difficult by using combinations of techniques;

1. Employ the pimpl idiom (already mentioned in the answer by parapura rajkumar)
2. Introduce an offset to members (including of the pimpl).  It will not necessarily be obvious to a programmer that the implementation details might be offset by 18 bytes, for example.
3. Supply a private `operator&()` for your class, which will have an effect of preventing the use of `&object` to get the address of an object.
4. Don't provide member functions that return `this`, and don't return an address of (or reference to) any private or protected class data.   And don't have public data.

The thing is, however, a determined enough programmer will find a way to work around all sorts of tricks like this, even without access to source code.    These sorts of tricks also have the unfortunate effect of making it harder for developers to use your class in more usual ways that you might intend.

Comment: Your answer is very useful, thanks. we cannot fobid pointer's type-casting but we can forbid getting address of an object. The thing is, by declaring an object of type `Foo` as a member of a custom class (`Bar` for example, which doesn't forbid getting its address), the user can easily access `Foo::value` by casting `Bar *` to `int *`. Now, I think there's really no way!

Comment: In addition, add extra members to duplicate information and check for internal coherency. add extra dummy members which should be modified...

Comment: *"we cannot fobid pointer's type-casting but we can forbid getting address of an object."* How so? There is http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [PIMPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) idiom and never include the implementation class headers as part of your library.

```
class A
{
    Aimpl* a_;
public:
    int getValue();
};
```

Now users can access but never know the internals of Aimpl to modify it.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Aimpl *a_`? It also doesn't prevent someone from changing the value if they want to, it just makes it a bit more difficult.

Comment: I agree with @Adam, people can access `a_`, hence can access where `a_` point to.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent anyone to write seemingly valid and working code as you're showing.

Seemingly because

```
 *p = 5678;
```

is actually undefined behaviour, and can't be relied on giving the same results as yours.